# Issues compiling in stdc++ using gcc/g++ in a 'c' program

Tags: c, gcc, g++, std

I have an issue of not being able to compile in the stdc++ library into my c program.  I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, gcc 4.9.

My question is: is it possible to compile in the stdc++ into a c program. And can this also be done using the armhf-linux cross compiler/libraries?

I'm using the following command line to compile:

```
g++ -c cppfile.cpp
gcc -o cfile -lstdc++ cppfile.o cfile.c
```

I've also tried using g++ instead of gcc but I get the same errors.

My main file is:

```
// cfile.c
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "cppfile.h"

int main()
{
    printf("Hello"); 
    myFunction();

    return 0;
}
```

My C++ file is here:

```
// cppfile.cpp
#include <string> 

using namespace std;

extern "C" {
int myFunction()
{
    std::string s = "hi";
    return 1;
}
}
```

Header file:

```
// cppfile.h
int myFunction();
```

The compile output is as follows:

```
cppfile.o: In function `myFunction':
cppfile.cpp:(.text+0xf): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::allocator()'
cppfile.cpp:(.text+0x27): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)'
cppfile.cpp:(.text+0x36): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
cppfile.cpp:(.text+0x4a): undefined reference to `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()'
cppfile.cpp:(.text+0x5f): undefined reference to `std::allocator<char>::~allocator()'
cppfile.o:(.eh_frame+0x13): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'     collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate, but I couldn't find a question like this.

Comment: Change `cppfile.h` to effectively read `extern "C" int myFunction();` for C++ compilation using `#ifdef __cplusplus` guards (just like in system include files in `/usr/include`)  lest you `#include` your `cppfile.h` header in a C++ file and wind up with *another* set of `undefined reference` errors.  If you don't do that, any C++ code that tries to call `myFunction()` will try to find [the mangled symbol name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#C.2B.2B).

Comment: 1) compile each *.c file separately, do not try to compile and link in the same line. (note: compile/link on same line is possible, but need to do it right) 2) The gcc linker handles command line arguments in the order they are presented, left to right.  When it handles the `-l` parameter, it does not yet have unresolved references that need to be resolved.  Write the link command line in the order: `gcc <options> cppfile.o cfile.o -lstdc++`

Comment: when compiling/linking, remember that C++ mangles the names of all functions.  So the compile step(s) will need to result in object files that have the function names mangled

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
g++ -c cppfile.cpp
gcc -c cfile.c
g++ -o cfile  cppfile.o cfile.o
```